# Date from MySQL returns NULL

Tags: mysql, date, null

This is my table structure:

```
Datum (Timestamp)     |IP   |X (times visited)
2012-09-08 14:09:44    *      10
2012-09-08 13:20:01    *      34
```

I'm getting the data from mySQL using:

```
$Darray=array();
$q="SELECT FROM Datum from ips ORDER BY X DESC";
$rs=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());
while($rd=mysql_fetch_object($rs))
{
$Darray[]=$rd->X;
}
```

But when i try

```
var_dump($Darray[1]);
```

I get NULL.

I also tried using

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(Datum) from ips ORDER BY X DESC
```

But it doesn't change anything

Comment: You should use MySQLi instead of MySQL. You might realize in a year or so that your code can no longer work on most servers and you will have to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are putting the `X` column into your array instead of `Datum`, and it is likely null because your SQL is wrong.

```
// Create array to hold date values
$date_array = array();

// Get all dates from ips table ordered by X column
$q = "SELECT `Datum` FROM `ips` ORDER BY `X` DESC";

// Query mysql
$rs = mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());

// Loop through results as PHP objects
while( $rd = mysql_fetch_object($rs) ) {
    // put the Datum value into array
    $date_array[] = $rd->Datum;
}

// Dump the contents of the $date_array
var_dump($date_array);
```

Comment: Great... just added some additional comments and formatting. Would appreciate it if you could mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is wrong you have two FROM clauses (`FROM Datum from ips`):

```
$q="SELECT FROM Datum from ips ORDER BY X DESC";
```